# Mongodb and nodejs with express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

First of all excuse for my bad english but i will try my best to explain myself. Im a student who's trying to develop a nodejs project with express until now i was using as a db in a single json file and workig thru it. But now i want to migrate to Mongodb. i already imported my db with "mongoimport --db RestauranteSin" --collection "Restaurante" --file 'filename'" so it imported it ok.

Next thing im doing is creating a new endpoint

```
app.get('/mongoAllRestaurants', (req, res) => {
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";

MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/", { useNewUrlParser: true },(err, db) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db("RestauranteSin");
    var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID; 
    dbo.collection("Restaurante").find({_id:ObjectId("5bd218627c5b747cdb14c51e"), restaurantes: {$elemMatch : {titulo_restaurante: "BarJanny"}}}).toArray((err, result) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(result[0]);
      res.send(result);
      db.close();
    });
});
```

});

And my db is something like this:

```
[
"_id" : "345678987654",
"restaurantes": [
    {
        "titulo_restaurante": "example1",
        ... 
        ...
        ...
    },
    {
        "titulo_restaurante": "example2",
        ... 
        ...
        ...
    },
    ...
    ...
    ...
]
```

]

And this is the question. ¿Why if im doing the query it returns all my db with no filter? I a lot of combination of query's and it always return to me all the db or empty array ? I need as result something like this:

```
{
        "titulo_restaurante": "example1",
        ... 
        ...
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two errors in the query code:

- You are missing the `new` command. When you find for a document of an
  _id, you are finding for an ObjectID object with a specific inizialization (who is the id string), so you must create the object
  you are searching for: new ObjectId('idString'), the result will be
  an ObjectID that can be compared with the documents _id for find the
  right document (Notice that with var `ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;` you are requiring the ObjectID class of mongodb package and assign it to the var ObjectId).
- Projection inside find is deprecated. You could use projection(), like this: `db.collection('collectionName').find({ field: value }).project({ field: value })`
  In the case of your query is: `dbo.collection("Resturante").find({ _id: new ObjectId('5bd218627c5b747cdb14c51e') }).project({ restaurantes: { . $elemMatch: { titulo_restaurante: "BarJanny" } } })`

So your query without errors is:

```
dbo.collection("Resturante")
    .find({ _id: new ObjectId('5bd218627c5b747cdb14c51e') })
    .project({ restaurantes: { $elemMatch: { titulo_restaurante: "BarJanny" } } })
    .toArray((err, result) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result[0].restaurantes[0]); // { titulo_restaurante: 'BarJanny' }
        db.close();
    });
```

Add `res.send(result)` before `db.close()` for the GET response.

Comment: Hi, first thank you for answer my question, and i already try this but i have no idea why it keeps returning me the entire db, can't understand what's wrong....it's not querying.

Comment: Hi, it's a pleasure. I've changed the response and i've personally tried the code. Now it works. The first  problem i've mentioned was correct, but the second one is that projection inside the .find() is deprecated (see the new solution).